# Recursive/cyclic call to useEffect - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have checked stackoverflow and although there are similar questions, none of them solve the casuistry of my problem.

I have a component that triggers the useEffect if it receives an update from the parent element. So it calls a function that refreshes some components and loads new ones. The problem is that at the time this function is executed, some elements are modified and the useEffect is triggered again. I've already tried modifying the parameters of the useEffect so that it only refreshes on certain values, but it doesn't work properly.

The error:

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies
```

Code:

```
export const PsqMainPanel = ({idtest}) => {
 
    const [currentTest, setCurrentTest] = useState(<PsqEmpty />);
 
    const loadUnitTest = useCallback ((idtest) => {
        console.log(idtest);
        const newTest = getPsqTestLoader(idtest);
        if (newTest == null)
            return;
        //Load new test.
        console.log("Load new test: " + {idtest});
        setCurrentTest(newTest);
    }, []);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        loadUnitTest(idtest);
    }, [idtest]);
 
    return(
        <>
        {currentTest}
        </>
    );
 
}
```

This is the code for the problematic Element. If you notice, the useEffect in this example is executed if idtest changes. I've tried it with [], but clearly it only fires the useEffect at startup (doesn't run if idtest changes), also without [] which runs cyclically, and with currentTest, which then runs cyclically as well.

What I do is load the PsqMainPanel with an "empty" Element (PsqEmpty). The getPsqTestLoader function returns another React element depending on the identifier it has (const newTest = getPsqTestLoader(idtest), once the React element is successfully generated by the function, it is loaded into the parent Element (setCurrentTest (newTest)). It loads correctly, but it keeps calling useEffect indefinitely How can I NOT trigger the useEffect function if the value in the loadUnitTest function is changed?

Thank you!

Comment: This should work fine, the effect does not depend upon the `currentTest` state that it changes. Can you show us how `<PsqMainPanel>` is used, maybe it's the parent component that keeps passing new `testId`s?

Comment: Btw, are you calling `setCurrentTest` anywhere else in the panel? Or is the effect actually asynchronous? If not, you probably could just use `useMemo` instead of a state and an effect.

Comment: Sure, I add the key lines separately, and the entire code of the element (PsqMain) that makes use of PsqMainPanel. Thank you

Comment: what is psqMenuTest code? i think you should give us a reproducible code by using a codesandbox or something similar (not all the code but at least a working code with that infinite loop problem).

Comment: I was creating a simple reproducible code for this question, and now its working ¬¬' I dunnot what did I change in order to make it work. Im searching now, maybe it can help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the culprit is the `switchTest` which is setting the `currentTest` in your parent component. You're passing it to the `callback` prop which I believe is calling the function as soon as it gets it. Can you try passing `(id)=>switchTest(id)` to the `callback` prop instead ?

Comment: I tried using this solution and it works too! checked! Thank you!